# colour options in tikz are good on dvi and ps but not so good in pdflatex and printing

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use tikz to produce graphics and then have some shading parts in black, some in gray. The graphics look good on DVI and PS and the printing is also good from these files. But when I use pdflatex to produce the file in PDF, the shaded parts do not look so black or gray as they are on dvi and ps. Attached is my LaTeX code and the image on pdf. Why does this happen?

```
    \documentclass[11pt, oneside, A4paper,final,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, latexsym, amscd, amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[modulo,left, displaymath]{lineno}
\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\normalfont\bfseries\small }
\usepackage{eurosans}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{curves}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphics, graphpap}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-eps}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=1.8245cm,right=1.85cm,bottom=1.69cm,bindingoffset=0.05cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pst-coil}
\begin{document}
\subsection*{APMOPS 2014 \rule{4.2cm}{.4pt}}

\begin{enumerate}[\scalebox{1.21}{\bf\arabic{enumi}.}]
\item Find the value of $29999+2999+299+29+9$.

\item  \parbox[t]{4.565in}{ $ABCD$ is  a parallelogram. $P, Q, R,$ and $S$ are the midpoints of the four sides of the parallelogram. If the area of the shaded region is 20 cm$^2$, find the area of the parallelogram $ABCD$.}
\hspace{1pt}
\raisebox{-38pt}[10pt]{\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{scale=.62}
\draw (3,3) -- (7,3) -- (6,1) -- (2,1) -- cycle;
\fill[color=black,fill=black,fill opacity=0.1] (3.4,2.2) -- (5.2,2.6) -- (5.6,1.8) -- (3.8,1.4) -- cycle;
\draw (6,1)-- (5,3);
\draw (3,3)-- (4,1);
\draw (2,1)-- (6.5,2);
\draw (7,3)-- (2.5,2);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=black] (2.86,3.34) node {$A$};
\draw[color=black] (7.16,3.28) node {$B$};
\draw[color=black] (6.43,1.02) node {$C$};
\draw[color=black] (1.66,1.1) node {$D$};
\draw[color=black] (5.16,3.28) node {$P$};
\draw[color=black] (6.764,1.82) node {$Q$};
\draw[color=black] (4.24,1.2) node {$R$};
\draw[color=black] (2.28,2.28) node {$S$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\item Jane added up  all the digits of the whole number
\[\underbrace{3\times 3\times 3\times \cdots \times 3}_{\text{product of  2012 of digits 3}},\]
and obtained a new number $N_1$. She then added up all the digits of $N_1$ and obtained another  number $N_2$. She continued doing this until she obtained a single digit number. Find the value of this new number.

\item  \parbox[t]{4.565in}{The diagram shows three circles of different diameters. The circumference of the smallest circle passes through the center of the middle circle and the circumference of the middle circle passes through the centre of the largest circle. Find the ratio of the shaded area to the unshaded area.
 }
\hspace{1pt}
\raisebox{-62pt}[10pt]{\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{scale=.3025182}
%\draw(4,1) circle (8cm);
\draw(8,1) circle (4cm);
\draw(10,1) circle (2cm);
\draw(11,1) circle (1cm);


\fill[color=black,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.1](8,1) circle (4cm);
\fill[color=black,fill=white,fill opacity=0.1](10,1) circle (2cm);
\fill[color=black,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.1](11,1) circle (1cm);

\end{tikzpicture}}


\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{scale=.5182}
\draw(2.999,2) circle (1cm);
\draw(5.17,1.98) circle (1.18cm);
\draw(3.876,0.063) circle (1.12cm);
\begin{scriptsize}
\fill [color=black] (3,2) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (3.14,2.28) node {$P$};
\fill [color=black] (5.18,1.98) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (5.34,2.26) node {$R$};
\fill [color=black] (3.86,0.06) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (4.02,0.34) node {$Q$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: I don't notice any code for shading in gray. Can you please post a full example that includes the preamble, starting at `\documentclass{...}` and ends at `\end{document}`? You can edit it into your post, as I have done, by clicking the `edit` button below the post

Comment: Even I put it in black, it is not so black on pdf when typset by pdflatex. It is fine on ps and div.

Comment: What do you mean "not so black"? Could it be your pdf reader or screen? Can you post the whole document including the preamble and also a screenshot comparison? Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
\fill[color=black,fill=black,fill opacity=0.1]
```

with `fill opacity` of 0.1 --- meaning 10%. So a black patch over a figure will result in 10% black and 90% of what is below.

In `dvi` and `ps` via ghostscript you'll probably have a black fill because the driver don't support transparency...

Try with `fill opacity=1`.

From section 21.2 of the manual (v.2.10-CVS):

> ```
>     /tikz/draw opacity= value    (no default)
> ```
>
> This option sets “how transparent” lines should be. A value of 1 means “fully opaque” or
>   “not trans- parent at all,” a value of 0 means “fully transparent” or
>   “invisible.” A value of 0.5 yields lines that are semitransparent.
>   Note that when you use PostScript as your output format, this option
>   works only with recent versions of Ghostscript.

...and a similar thing for `fill opacity`.

Comment: If this is the solution, please consider marking the question as answered...

Comment: How to mark it as asnwered?

Comment: Please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers